# All transmission gears shift too fast-- odometer shows 80mph when at 30-35

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, cooling, expedition

2000 Ford Expedition 5.4l awd xlt almost 250,000 miles.

Cold streak came in. Used 4wd to run a few close errands no problems. A couple of days later, no coolant in reservoir. Made a short trip to get more coolant (and oil as it was a little low), filled the reservoir (the reservoir is the entry point on these models).

When on the way there, I noticed my transmission wigging out. It would switch through all gears too fast and show 70 to 80 miles per hour when actually only going 30 to 40. Rpm would stay at 2000 unless I pressed it, so I stayed slow in last gear.

After filling it back up with coolant, going back home, same thing with transmission. It never got to full overheating but smoked up a storm when I got home. Coolant was gone from reservoir again. I saw it leaking in the back, toward rear of engine, but saw other fluid leaking also further back, passenger side. I suppose it could be two separate problems but does anyone know if a coolant leak can cause a transmission to act like that in 1st gen expeditions?

Also, 4wd will not disengage by switch.

I admit, I didn't check tranny fluid yet and will but was curious if anyone has experienced this.

Comment: If this is a 4wd and not an AWD, you've got it stuck in low range. Put it in Neutral (transmission) and then switch it from 4WL to 4WH, then Auto or 2WD from that point. Wait for it to switch at each point.

Comment: Thank you but it's awd. I have the option to change to all-time 4wd. The light stays on all-time no matter what I switch it to, and I can tell it's stuck in all-time. Trying to get it to regular (awd standard). Either way, Idk or think that's the biggest of my worries based on the descriptions.

Comment: Your description of what it's doing sure sounds like it's stuck in low range. The biggest clue to that would be the speedo stating it's going 80mph when it's only going 35. The speed is measured at the output of the transmission, which is before the transfer case. If it's not switchable, then there's an issue with the transfer case.

Comment: Could this have caused a coolant issue as well, keeping in mind it wasn't used between when it was fine and what's stated in my question body? Except for idling for 5 to 10 min in park to keep the battery from failing anyway... There's definitely fluid leaking.

Comment: This should really have nothing to do with your coolant issues. With the fluid leaking, it can only go one of three places: on the ground; out the exhaust; in the crankcase. What you're describing seems like two separate issues.

Comment: I do know coolant systems in and of themselves. I wasn't sure if the cooling problem led to a transmission cooler line problem or if the computer messes up timing if it reads too hot. But with the 4wd light still on I should've known. I checked oil and tranny fluid. Both ok; that's good. I had a 98 in the past and even when I had an instance of 4wd not disengaging, it didn't switch through so fast.

Comment: Oops I wasn't done. Anyway, when it got warmer, I switch gears a bit while trying to flip the 4wd switch and it finally disengaged. Took it out for a little test with coolant added. The gears seem to be better but I can't test at high speeds. I think the coolant is either a freeze plug or heater hose(s) down lower based on where it's leaking. Thanks for the help. I'll narrow it down.